# Customize HTTP 400 error page in IIS 7

Tags: php, iis, iis-7, web-config, http-error

Is their any way to display a custom page for HTTP 400 error.
I'm using PHP with IIS7 in Windows server 2008 R2

I checked Microsoft website and got [this info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753103%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). It tells that we can't customize it.

I found another article regarding this via ".htaccess" file (http://perishablepress.com/custom-http-errors-via-htaccess/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. We cannot display a custom page for HTTP 400 error using PHP in IIS7 in windows server 2008 R2.

Please refer the link for more details.([Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753103%28v=ws.10%29.aspx))